# TypeError: this.$refs.scroll.scrollToVerticalOffset is not a function

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue

In my template I have:

```
<ScrollView ref="scroll" row="1" verticalAlignment="center">
  ...
</ScrollView>
```

In my methods I have:

```
scrollToBottom() {
  var scroll = this.$refs.scroll;
  scroll.scrollToVerticalOffset(scroll.scrollableHeight, true);
},
```

But I get an error saying:

> [Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: this.$refs.scroll.scrollToVerticalOffset is not a function"

Comment: this.$refs.scroll.nativeView solved it.